# C# ¿Que resultado me devuelven estos problemas?

Tags: c#

De que otra forma podría realizar estas mismas operaciones (usando for, while o algo parecido, exceptuando el problema 3)

está en C#

```
internal long[][][] nums;
internal long[][][] tree;

// Problema 1
long sum += tree[i][j][k];

// Problema 2
int value
nums[x][y][z] = value;

// problema 3
            long[][][] newArray = new long[size1][][];
            for (int array1 = 0; array1 < size1; array1++)
            {
                newArray[array1] = new long[size2][];
                if (size3 > -1)
                {
                    for (int array2 = 0; array2 < size2; array2++)
                    {
                        newArray[array1][array2] = new long[size3];
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: porque dices "exceptuando el problema3" ? ademas no entiendo los problema, que hay que hacer solo veo una linea de codigo

Answer (score 1):

Si la idea es iterar un array de varias dimensiones vas a necesitar tantos for como dimensiones tengas.

[Matrices](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/arrays)

entonces usarias

```
long sum = 0;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
       for(int k=0; k<10; k++)
          sum += tree[i][j][k];
```

de esta forma sumarias conociendo la cantidad de items que tiene cada dimension

Nota: como es una linea no necesitas las `{ }` en los `for`

---

Si necesitas iterar sin conocer la cantidad de items de cada dimension te puede ayudar el

[Array.GetUpperBound(Int32) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=netframework-4.5)